# Heart failure and pleural effusion

Tags: lungs, pulmonology, heart-failure

Why does pleural effusion usually occurs in the right hemithorax in acute heart failure? Could someone explain the mechanism? Thank you.

Comment: where did you see/read that pulmonary edema usually occurs in the right hemithorax? as far as I typically see it's generally in both lung fields on a chest x-ray when it's present

Comment: Sorry i just realized i wrote it wrong. It should be pleural effusion, not pulmonary edema. I cannot say any reference textbook. Because it is written on a book for medical exams.

Comment: thanks for clarifying... I still have the same question... where have you seen that pleural effusions occur on the right instead of the left? can you cite that in your question?

Comment: @VanceLAlbaugh I am curious about this question though I don't know the answer. Searching for the source of this information I think OP might have it slightly wrong; bilateral pleural effusion is by far most common, but unilateral pleural effusion is typically in the right. This seems to be commonly reported, [here's one example](https://www.thieme-connect.com/products/ejournals/html/10.1055/s-0030-1269828), [here is another](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/000293435790339X).

Comment: completely agree @BryanKrause